# how to extend Double and Int in Swift with the same function

Tags: swift, generics, integer, double

I want to create an extension for Swift Double, Int, and other numeric types that support the random(in:) function, like so:

```
extension Double {
    // function to generate multiple random numbers of type
    static func random(in range: ClosedRange<Self>, count: Int) -> [Self] {
        var values = [Self]()
        if count > 0 {
            for _ in 0..<count {
                values.append(Self.random(in: range))
            }
        }
        return values
    }
}
```

How do I do this without creating a separate extension for each type?

Comment: Are you sure this is even worth it? It's typical to just write something like `(0...5).map { Double.random(in: 0...1) }`

Comment: By the way, that `if` statement doesn't do anything. If `count` is `0`, then `0..<count` is an empty range, which would already make the `for` loop do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the second point. On the first point, that was my implementation but I was getting this error: Cannot convert value of type '() -> Double' to expected argument type '(ClosedRange<Int>.Element) throws -> Double' (aka '(Int) throws -> Double'). I therefore converted the Ints to Doubles and then generated the array of Doubles, but thought this looked terrible.

Comment: Oh, I remember that on the second point, I wanted to cater for negative values of count i.e. return an empty array for values less than 1.

Comment: I think you can express that intent more clearly by moving the precondition to the first line of you function: `guard count > 0 else { return [] }`. As for the type error you're getting, could you please show the exact code you tried? I'm just guessing here, so I can't replicate your error

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I see that is much better way to code. I just paste this into the playground to generate the above error:

print((0...5).map { Double.random(in: 0...1) })

Comment: I can fix it like this: print((0...5).map { Double($0) }.map { Double.random(in: 0...1) }), but it generates a warning (although it works). Warning: Result of 'Double' initializer is unused

Comment: Ohhhhh I misread the original error. Here's what's going on. I made a mistake in my first snippet (I just typed it out directly in the comment and never actually ran it), `print((0...5).map { Double.random(in: 0...1) })`. The closure I'm passing to map is inferred to have type `() -> Double` (meaning that it takes no parameter). To fix that, you need to explicitly state that you have a parameter, and that you're ignoring its value, like: `(0...5).map { _ in Double.random(in: 0...1) }`. Now it's inferred to have the correct type, `(Int) -> Double` (it takes an Int, and discards it)

Comment: I can also explain why your second snippet (`print((0...5).map { Double($0) }.map { Double.random(in: 0...1) })`) works but gives a warning. Fundamentally, the type-checker found the only correct solution which makes this expression pass type-checking, and that is  a if it were written as `print((0...5).map({ Double($0) } as (Int) -> Void).map({ Double.random(in: 0...1) } as () -> Double))`. The lack of a parameter on the second closure is only valid if the first closure returns `Void`. But if the first closure returns `Void`, that means the `Double($0)` needs to be discarded, so it warns you

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Don't know how you know these things, but am extremely grateful. It works perfectly as stated.

Comment: Glad to help! I can tell you how I know. Firstly `(0...5).map { _ in ___ }` is a really common pattern (hence why I was asking if it was worth writing an extension for it to begin with), it’s like `Array(repeating: ___, count: 5)`, except it generates a separate value for each array element (v important for classes, where you don’t want to have an array of 5 references to the same one object). The error about the missing `_ in` is pretty spot on and detailed, I just glossed over it for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really since there is no common protocol involved here but as far as I understand the types that has the method `random(in:)` can be grouped into types conforming to two protocols so you need only two implementations

```
// Double & Float
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {
    static func random(in range: ClosedRange<Self>, count: Int) -> [Self] where Self.RawSignificand: FixedWidthInteger {
       var values = [Self]()
       if count > 0 {
           for _ in 0..<count {
               values.append(Self.random(in: range))
           }
       }
       return values
   }
}

// Int & UInt
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    static func random(in range: ClosedRange<Self>, count: Int) -> [Self] {
       var values = [Self]()
       if count > 0 {
           for _ in 0..<count {
               values.append(Self.random(in: range))
           }
       }
       return values
   }
}
```